# I found a bug in Batch. How can I circumvent this bug?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

CMD is misinterpreting code on the false side of an `if` statement, resulting in a crash.

Here is some test code, which fails should the end user enter `y` or `Y`:

```bash
@Echo Off

Set "var="
Set "input="

:YorN
Set /P "input=Leave var empty? [Y(crash)|N]"
(Set input) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X "input=Y input=N" 1>NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo YorN
 
If /I "%input%" == "n" Set "var=content1;content2;"

If Not "%var%" == "" (
    For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%G In ("%var:~0,-1%") Do If Not "%%G" == "" Echo "%%G" "%%H"
) Else (
    Echo As per your choosing, var is empty. Because of the if  statement the "for" command didn't get interpreted and CMD didn't crash. You will not see this message.
)

Pause
Exit /B
```

This version however, with only one minor line break change works as intended.

```bash
@Echo Off

Set "var="
Set "input="

:YorN
Set /P "input=Leave var empty? [Y(crash)|N]"
(Set input) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X "input=Y input=N" 1>NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo YorN
 
If /I "%input%" == "n" Set "var=content1;content2;"

If Not "%var%" == "" (
    For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%G In ("%var:~0,-1%"
    ) Do If Not "%%G" == "" Echo "%%G" "%%H"
) Else (
    Echo As per your choosing, var is empty. Because of the if  statement the "for" command didn't get interpreted and CMD didn't crash. You will see this message.
)

Pause
Exit /B
```

Could somebody please explain to me what is causing this issue, or confirm that this is a bug in cmd.exe?

Comment: If you find a bug in batch, report it at micrsoft not here. Or what do you think how we can help you?

Comment: @Jens I don't think Microsoft would or should "fix" said bug, because it might change how existing code is interpreted. I want to share this bug because others might have the same problem

Comment: But this is not a knowlege base

Comment: Well, if it is so important to you, I can add an arbitrary question to my post and you can help me with that

Comment: It is not important for me. That are the rules of SO

Comment: I have updated your code @MartinDerTolle, to use more robust and correct syntax, and reproduced your reported problem. I have also, as you can see, included a working version, with a single minor change which circumvents that problem _(part of your question)_. Perhaps, when or if the question is reopened you will get the help you wanted with regards the reason, or a better solution.. _I myself will not take part, due to your general attitude towards me_.

Comment: Thank you for proposing this solution @Compo . I did not know, that there was a missing line break. Neither your initial answer nor CMD command "help for" specify that there is supposed to be one there. How do I know when to put a line break? Should I just do that by gut feeling?

Comment: No idea, what's exactly happening here, but delayed expansion seems to cure it: `For /F ... In ("!var:~0,-1!") Do ...` (with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` of course)

Comment: On the other hand, `for /f ... in ("%var%") do ...` does also work (and there is no reason to remove the last char - at least not in this  example; `delims=;` will take care of it)

Comment: @MartinDerTolle, there isn't **supposed** to be one there, I added one optionally, and it fixed the problem without offering an obvious explanation. My idea was to submit a workaround, within the question itself, without answering/fixing it directly.

Comment: Well, thank you both a lot. A workaround is enough in my books. My solution needed to work without SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, because my actual variables can contain exclamation marks

Comment: Also to me, it will remain a bug, because it is probably an afterthought to the "new" %var:~0,-1% syntax and they didn't change the help docs.
Also they might've been testing with delayed expansion in mind

Comment: @MartinDerTolle, I reverted your most recent change, because the question area is not the right place for providing fixed code; as it stands now, there is a reproducible issue…

Comment: In addition @MartinDerTolle, you should note that in my initial, now deleted, answer, (improving your original code, and not exhibiting the reported problem), I specifically used `("%var%")`, instead of `("%var:0,-1%")` too. _I'm sure you meant to credit me for being first to suggest that, but forgot_.

Comment: I should add @MartinDerTolle, that there is very likely nothing to stop you from using delayed expansion. What you need to do is not be lazy by enabling it for the entire script, it only requires to be enabled when needed, or more specifically, not enabled when the variable is defined.

Comment: @Compo I apologize that I did not notice that in your initial answer. Since you deleted it, I can't confirm or deny it. I'm sorry if I gave you unnecessary attitude. I myself was a little irritated from the unproper reformatting of my code. (I used blockquotes instead of code formatting and you didn't remove the double spaces that acted as line breaks before when you changed it to code formatting.) I guess I was stuck up on that and my question being closed, when I was still very obviously confused about the answers I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have found (referring to [revision 13](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73235489/13) of your question) is something that I consider a bug (or at least a terrible design flaw) – **but** the problem is neither the `if` nor the `for` statement, it is the **sub-string** syntax:

If you follow the [percent expansion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912) very carefully, you may notice, that sub-string expansion (`%VAR:~[integer][,[integer]]%`) or sub-string substitution (`%VAR:[*]search=[replace]%`) behaves odd in case variable `VAR` is not defined. Here is an [excerpt of that post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7970912/38) with the most relevant sections ***highlighted***:

> **Phase 1) Percent Expansion** Starting from left, scan each character for `%` or `<LF>`. If found then
>
> - **1.05 (truncate line at `<LF>`)**
> - If the character is `<LF>` then
>
>   - Drop (ignore) the remainder of the line from the `<LF>` onward
>   - ***Goto Phase 2.0***
> - Else the character must be `%`, so proceed to 1.1
> - **1.1 (escape `%`)** *skipped if command line mode*
> - […]
> - **1.2 (expand argument)** *skipped if command line mode*
> - […]
> - **1.3 (expand variable)**
> - […]
> - Else if command extensions are enabled then
>   […]
>
>   - If next character is `%` then
>     […]
>   - Else if next character is `:` then
>
>     - If VAR is undefined then
>
>       - If batch mode then
>         ***Remove `%VAR:` and continue scan.***
>       - […]
>     - […]
> - **1.4 (strip `%`)**
>
>   - […]

Applying this to your code portions, we can conclude the following:

- **First code portion:**

  If `var` is not defined, `%var:~0,-1%` becomes parsed to `~0,-1%`, because of ***Remove `%VAR:` and continue scan*** in the above excerpt of Phase 1, leaving behind the remaining command line `~0,-1%") Do If Not "%%G" == "" Echo "%%G" "%%H"`, which is interpreted as:

  - the literal string `~0,1`,
  - the (undefined) variable `%") Do If Not "%` (which becomes stripped),
  - the (undefined) variable `%G" == "" Echo "%` (which becomes stripped),
  - the (undefined) variable `%G" "%` (which becomes stripped),
  - and the remainder `%H"` (which the single `%`-sign becomes removed from),

  constituting the command line     `For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %G In ("~0,-1H"` after Phase 1. The next line `) Else (` provides an expected closing parenthesis, but there is `Do` expected rather than `Else`. That is why the specific error message `Else was unexpected at this time.` arises.

  Hence the `%`-sign in the fragment `~0,-1%` is considered as an opening one for another (yet undefined) variable, impairing the whole remainder of the command line.
- **Second code portion:**

  If `var` is not defined, `%var:~0,-1%` also becomes parsed to `~0,-1%`, because of ***Remove `%VAR:` and continue scan*** in the above excerpt of Phase 1, but leaving behind the remaining command line `~0,-1%"`, resulting in just the literal string `~0,-1"` (with the `%`-sign stripped).

  In this situation however, there is a line-break (`<LF>`) following, so Phase 1 is ended because of ***Goto Phase 2.0*** and so, parsing newly begins with Phase 1 in the next line.

The key to all this is the statement ***and continue scan***, meaning that from that point on, the next detected `%`-sign is recognised as an *opening* one.

---

> ### How can I circumvent this bug?

To circumvent the described issue, you have got the following options:

1. To avoid command blocks in the problematic code section `If Not "%var%" == "" ( … ) Else ( … )` by using the `goto` command and labels:

   ```cmd
   If Not Defined var GoTo UnDef
   For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%G In ("%var:~0,-1%") Do If Not "%%G" == "" Echo "%%G" "%%H"
   GoTo :Next
   :UnDef
   Echo As per your choosing, var is empty. Because of the "if" statement the "for" command didn't get interpreted and CMD didn't crash. You will see this message.
   :Next
   ```
2. To utilise [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is applied to individual tokens rather than whole command lines, rendering them independent from each other; the section behind `in` in a `for`-loop constitutes such a token, according to the [delayed expansion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912):

   ```cmd
   If Not "%var%" == "" (
       SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%G In ("!var:~0,-1!") Do EndLocal & If Not "%%G" == "" Echo "%%G" "%%H"
   ) Else (
       Echo As per your choosing, var is empty. Because of the "if" statement the "for" command didn't get interpreted and CMD didn't crash. You will see this message.
   )
   ```

   Therein, delayed expansion is only active until parsing of the `in` clause because of the `endlocal` behind `do` (which is only executed once because there is only one loop iteration).

Answer (score 4):

There is no bug, but the behavior is not obvious.

A minimal example shows the problem.

```
@echo off

set "var="
set "other=content"
echo First char of var is "%var:~0,1%" my other var=%other%
```

You get:

> First char of var is "~0,1other

If you add any text to `var` it works as expected.

The variable `var` is undefined, not empty!
The problem is the expansion rule of undefined variables, the parser stops the variable expansion part, if it finds a double colon in an expression, but the variable is undefined.
In this case the parser ignores (and removes) the variable expansion after reading `%var:`.
But the the parser looks at the remaining line of `~0,1%" my other var=%other%`.
It splits the line to

1. `~0,1`  -- Normal text
2. `%" my other var=%`  -- This is a percent expansion of the variable with the name `" my other var=`, this variable is undefined, cmd.exe removes the complete part
3. `other`  -- Normal text
4. `%`  -- The trailing opening percent is removed, because there is no other percent sign

In your complicated example the line feed seems to solve the situation, because the part `If Not "%%G" ...` is on a separate line and the first percent of `%%G` is not used as the closing percent of the expression `%") Do If Not "%`.
In the failure case, it gets worse, because the closing parenthesis of the FOR block is removed and then the FOR command scans the rest of the file for a closing parenthesis and that ends in total rubbish.

For better understanding you could read:
[SO: Percent Expansion Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115) from [@dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)